# Relationship Between Coefficient of Friction and Coefficient of Restitution

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, collision

Is there a formula that relates the coefficient of friction, specifically kinetic friction, with the coefficient of restitution?

Comment: What makes you believe there _is_ a relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe so.

The coefficient of kinetic friction pertains to surfaces sliding with respect to one another, i.e., sliding or surface friction. The coefficient of restitution has to do with inelastic vs elastic behavior during collisions, i.e., internal friction between elements of a solid.

Hope this helps.